# Jquery wildcard not select not working

Tags: jquery, find, wildcard

I have a form to send off various orders, this happens in th ebackground via ajax. Only one order can be sent at a time so when a Send button is clicked I want to hide the other send buttons but still show this one.

The id of the table cells is "send(order_number)1". My jquery code is

```
$('#all_orders').find('[id^=send]').not('#send'+order_id+'1').replaceWith();
```

Where +order_id+ is the clicked order.

Currently it just hides all of the buttons.

Each order is repeated in a table within a div with id of all_orders.

```
<td id="send<?=$order['id']?>1">
    <input type='button'  class='submit subtitle' value='Send' onclick="export_leads(<?=$order['id']?>, '<?=$orders[$order['id']]['type']?>', '<?=$orders[$order['id']]['amount']?>', <?=$client_id?>)">
</td>

 function export_leads(order_id, type, amount, client_id){
   $('#all_orders').find('[id^=send]').not('#send'+order_id+'1').replaceWith();

   //Ajax send order code
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../includes/ajax.php",
    data: "type="+type+"&amount="+amount+"&client_id="+client_id,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg)
    {
        $('#send_panel'+order_id).replaceWith(msg);
    }
   });
}
```

Comment: Try this `$('#all_orders').find('[id^="send"]').not('#send'+order_id+'1').replaceWith();`

Comment: ^don't think that's needed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code you posted. http://jsfiddle.net/czxwobx1/5/. May be your order_id parameter is not fetched correctly. Show your code how you make order_id on click. Problem lies there.

Comment: Tried that Amit, didn't work unfortunately. I've alerted the order_id number in the ajax function and it comes through correctly. I will post more code above...

Comment: I've found a different way of doing it now thanks. Strange the original way didn't work though.